# jQuery pass value in anchor tag when clicked the value not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have this data when clicked will pass the value into the input textbox using jQuery. I am using also PHP for the backend. The script and data is passed into the input textbox correctly only that the value is only the same. How will I able to do this that the data being passed into the input textbox will be dynamically render.

This is the script below.  In the backend:

```
<?php foreach($mondays as $key=>$monday): ?>
    <?php echo "<a id='data-monday-".$key."' href='javascript:void(0);' 
        data-id='$monday' >$monday</a>";  ?>
    <?php echo "<br>";?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In my jQuery script below:

```
<?php $mondays = json_decode($postRoom['day_monday']); ?>
<?php foreach($mondays as $key=>$monday): ?>
    $("#data-monday-<?php echo $key;?>" ).click(function(){
        // var keys = $(this).attr("<?php echo $key;?>");
        var keys = $('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]').data('id');
        console.log(keys)
        $("#selectTime").val(keys);
    });
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My input texbox below:

```
<label for="time" class="form-label">Select time from the table</label>
<input type="text" id="selectTime" name="checkinTimes" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Really not clear what you're trying to do, but it *looks like* you want to change this `var keys = $('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]').data('id');` to `var keys = $(this).data("id")`

Comment: thanks dude! it works now! i change the code